# GridView or TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/645/weatherscreenmockupoutl.png

I am asking myself whats the best way to code this layout. Basicly i just need to know how to get seven columns with an equal width.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Table layout will work fine....

Comment: Downvoted because: The Image in the Link is not accessable anymore so we cannot see what the original question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it is the equal width that you want, you can go for linearLayout with children of equal weight. check out the following xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    layout:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id = "@+id/firstcolumn"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
    >
    // do the same for your rest of the six children

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

`TableLayout` seems better, because the number of columns won't change. With `GridView` you have to add adapters and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a good combination of TableLayout with TableRow, and make rows and columns as you want, very easy.

This is an example with 2x2 grid with 4 buttons (put insidea a LinearLayout for example):

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use a gridview. Try someothing like this :

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="7" />
```

Comment: Seems like the obvious solution, but for static content I'd still go with LinearLayout. GridView needs an adapter to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/>
<GridView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="7"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

try this..